# Fragments onCreateView() bundle. Where does it come from?

Tags: android, bundle

I'm starting an Activity through the usual means:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, DualPaneActivity.class);
startIntent.putExtras(((SearchPageFragment) currentFragment).getPageState());
startActivity(startIntent);
```

When this activity loads, it places a Fragment in a frame like so:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
Fragment currentFragment = fragment;
currentFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
transaction.replace(R.id.singlePane, currentFragment);  
transaction.commit();
```

Seems simple, right?

However, you can inside of onCreateView() method access three separate bundles (four, if you include the one included in the Fragment's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // Fill state information
    Bundle bundle;
    if(savedInstanceState != null)  bundle = savedInstanceState; // 1       
    else if(getArguments() != null) bundle = getArguments();     // 2
    else                            bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras(); // 3
    setPageState(bundle);   
}
```

In the above instance, I've worked out from trial and error that the bundle I want is the second one, the one retrieved from `getArguments()`.

From my understanding the third one from `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();` is actually calling the Bundle from the intent used to start containing activity. I also know from experimentation that `savedInstanceState` seems to always be null. But where is it coming from and **why** is it null?

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) says this:

> savedInstanceState    If non-null, this fragment is being re-constructed
>   from a previous saved state as given here.

That doesn't help me - It's bugging me more than stopping me from moving on. Can someone help me out with this annoyance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, `onCreateView` and `onCreate()` are both passed the bundle from `onSaveInstanceState()`.

So if you override `onSaveInstanceState()` and put data in the bundle, you should be able to retrieve it in `onCreateView()`.  That is why the documentation says that the bundle will be non-null when the fragment is re-constructed from a previous saved state.